# is there a way to get user''s all friends profile pictures without using access_token?

Tags: php, facebook

For example, can I use the following method to get any user's friends? what should the access_token field be?

```
$friends = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?access_token=...'),true);
```

Is it possible to create a php page that when we only input a user's id or name without logging into the user's account, it returns all his/her friends' profile pictures automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q:is there a way to get user''s all friends profile pictures without using access_token?

A: programatically - NO (else you may still use standard facebook webpage)

Q: what should the access_token field be?

A: you gain it when you login to facebook using graph api - it is related to the user and the application (AppID) specified during login.

Q:Is it possible to create a php page that when we only input a user's id or name without logging into the user's account, it returns all his/her friends' profile pictures automatically?

A: Yes, but such user have to permit to your facebook user and your application to retrieve such data.

Comment: Thanks. A great help. Since there's no such user that will permit me to retrieve their data, I might change my application to the scenario to show user's friends' profile pictures when the user logs in to Facebook. What do you mean by "you gain it when you login to facebook using graph api"? Can you tell me the difference between the App access token and user access token? I think I'll use them when requesting the user's information by my website...

Answer (score 1):

Horatio, there's no between the App access token and user access token, just give it a try and you'll see this by yourself too. Fred from [Mansfield](http://www.experiencenottinghamshire.com/mansfield)